# fnDraw is not redraw the datatable in ajax done request

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

```
oTable = $('#SLData').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 'All']],
        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]], "pageLength": 10,
        'processing': true, 'serverSide': true,
        'sAjaxSource': '<?php echo base_url();?>dev.php/website/edit_categories_list',

        "columns": [null, null, null, null, null, {"orderable":false, "searchable": false}]
    });
```

this is server side data table and trying to redraw the table after some operation in ajax
calling `oTable.fnDraw();` in ajax done function but it is not redraw the datatable
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your datatable variable is `oT` but you use `oTable.fnDraw()`

Comment: You want to re-draw the datatable on some event ?

Comment: yes ...in ajax done request i want to refresh the serverside dataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first destroy the datatable with object and then try to initialize the datatable in ajax done function

```
oTable.fnDestroy();

$('#SLData').dataTable();
```

Try this code, I hope this is working.